# Car rental program C#

Tags: c#

I need help with my project for school. I have been working on it and finally figured out how to output the beginning odometer and ending odometer = total miles driven. For total cost, I need it to add $15 per day rented, plus $0.12 per mile. How would I do this? Here is the code I have now:

```
//Step 1: Declaring variables to store our information.
decimal beginningOdometerDecimal;
decimal endingOdometerDecimal;
decimal rentedDecimal;
decimal totalSaleDecimal;
decimal averageSalesDecimal;
decimal carsReturned;
decimal totalMilesDecimal;
decimal finalCostDecimal;

//Step 2: Get the information from the user.
beginningOdometerDecimal = Decimal.Parse(txtBegin.Text);
endingOdometerDecimal = Decimal.Parse(txtEnd.Text);
rentedDecimal = Decimal.Parse(txtRent.Text);

//Step 3: Mathmatematical Calculations.
totalMilesDecimal = endingOdometerDecimal - beginningOdometerDecimal;
finalCostDecimal = totalMilesDecimal * (Decimal)0.12 + rentedDecimal + 15;
```

As you see, I used finalCostDecimal is equal to totalmilesdecimal * $0.12 + rentedDecimal + 15. I don't think I used the right code. Can anyone please help me here? I am stuck and have tried a lot. Thanks!

Comment: This is basic 3rd grade arithmetic :(

Comment: @Gunnar Bates when you are starting to program it's probably easier to write down what you have to do before you write code. (e.g. write down all the calculations needed) I am assuming you should actually know how to make the calculation, but you're being confused by code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: At least he has some code to work with..

Comment: .. which means he already gave great effort on that! Carry on with your work.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, I was confused by the code :P. I know how to do math. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: These questions are rarely a problem with arithmetic, but how to express it in code. Which is what SO is for. +1 for asking instead of beating head against wall and giving up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `rentedDecimal` is the number of days the car was rented, then your calculation should be:

```
 finalCostDecimal = (totalMilesDecimal * 0.12m) + (rentedDecimal * 15.0m);
```

Comment: Should probably put in parentheses to make it easier to read :)

Answer (score 4):

$15 per day rented plus $0.12 per mile

($15 per day rented) plus ($0.12 per mile)

($15 * days rented) + ($0.12 * miles driven)

```
finalCostDecimal = (15 * rentedDecimal) + (0.12 * totalMilesDecimal)
```